# No overload matches Delegate (Silverlight datagrid conditional formatting)

Tags: c#, silverlight

I am trying to implement conditional formatting for a Silverlight Datagrid.  I am basing my code off Joel Wrobel's blog post here: http://weblogs.asp.net/joewrobel/archive/2009/01/25/conditional-formatting-in-the-silverlight-datagrid.aspx

My XAML resources:

```
<navigation:Page.Resources>
     <local:UniversalConverter x:Key="passConverter" Converting="ConvertPass" />
</navigation:Page.Resources>
```

My C# convertPass function:

```
private object ConvertPass(System.Object value, System.Type targetType, System.Object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int passRate;
        bool success = int.TryParse(value.ToString(), out passRate);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("TRY 1");
        if (!success)
        {
            return value;
        }

        Grid grid = new Grid();
        if (passRate == 1)
        {
            grid.Children.Add(new TextBlock { Text = string.Format("{0},(perfect)", passRate) });
            grid.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
        }
        else
        {
            grid.Children.Add(new TextBlock { Text = passRate.ToString() });
            grid.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        }
        return grid;
    }
```

Everything else is identical to Joel's post.  The error I get is: No overload for 'ConvertName' matches delegate 'UniversalConverterHandler

Searching for the error only results in asserting that the method and delegate signatures do not match.   In my case due to VS's adding them and copy/paste checks, I'm pretty sure that they do.  Any advice on what this could be (I'm new to Silverlight / C#) would be great.  Thanks

Comment: where and where does the error occurs ?

Comment: The error shows up upon build and Visual Studio's location for it is just the xaml file.

Answer (score 0):

The error you mention is referring to a method from Joel Wrobel's sample project i.e. '*ConvertName*'

You may want to search your project for a references to his ConvertName and change/remove them.

It is possible you have picked up a reference while cutting/pasting. Are you using his methods as well?

If not, please post more code. Cheers.

Comment: I have removed all references to 'ConvertName' (I was trying to implement only his code at one point) but now have the same error for the ConvertPass.  Will post more code.